# selective depth testing possibility in openGL

Tags: opengl, buffer, depth

Is there a way to enable depth testing only for the triangles belonging to sphere and leave the original depth buffer untouched and see only triangles of sphere facing camera ?

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
glDepthMask(false);
```

// rendering a primitive here (cone or sphere)

```
glDepthMask(true);
```

It looks like i can still see back faces of primitive.[image: cone rendering]

Comment: What language is this, by the way? You can make this more portable by using `GL_TRUE` and `GL_FALSE` instead of `true` and `false` (which are C++ keywords, but undefined in C).

Comment: The code is in C++. Thanks for your suggestion. I will change it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to enable depth testing only for the triangles belonging to sphere and leave the original depth buffer untouched and see only triangles of sphere facing camera?

No, but you don't have to. A sphere is a convex shape. Actually it's the absolute antetype of convex shapes. So all you have to do is getting rid of the triangles facing away from you. Easy enough: Enable backface culling:

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
```

Keep in mind that for this to work the winding of all the sphere's triangles must be consistent and when viewed from outside agree with the front side winding setting. Usually it is counter clock wise, but you could change it with `glFrontFace`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot to mention in my question that i have already enabled back face culling. I edited my question and attached a snapshot of the cone. Please have a look. I can still see the back faces somehow. Similar is the result for the sphere.

Comment: Problem solved. I disabled back face culling once again by mistake before drawing primitive.